# MySQL Error Code 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy tratando de crear una base de datos con este script en MySQL 
Pero me sale error 1215 de que no puede agregar el FK constraint lo he revisado pero no encuentro el problema. Podría ayudarme a ver el problema??

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mybase;

use mybase;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS montos (
    id_monto INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    monto NUMERIC(6 , 2 ) NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_monto)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ciudades (
    id_ciudad INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
    ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    provincia VARCHAR(50),
    agencia CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_ciudad)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bancos (
    id_banco INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
    banco VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    codigo VARCHAR(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_banco)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS asesores (
    id_asesor INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
    nombre VARCHAR(150) COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(150) COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI NOT NULL,
    est_asesor CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    update_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_asesor),
    UNIQUE KEY asesor_email_unique (email)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cliente (
    cedula VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    tipoID CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    nacionalidad VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    est_civil CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    sexo CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    id_ciudad INT(10) NOT NULL,
    telf_domicilio VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    celular_pers VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    actividad VARCHAR(100),
    profesion VARCHAR(100),
    lugar_trabajo VARCHAR(200),
    cargo VARCHAR(100),
    telefono_t VARCHAR(20),
    celular_t VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_t VARCHAR(255),
    email_t VARCHAR(100),
    ced_conyuge VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_conyuge VARCHAR(255),
    telf_conyuge VARCHAR(20),
    celular_conyuge VARCHAR(20),
    email_conyuge VARCHAR(100),
    nombre_RFamiliar VARCHAR(255),
    telf_RFamiliar VARCHAR(20),
    celular_RF VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_RLaboral VARCHAR(255),
    telf_RLaboral VARCHAR(20),
    celular_RL VARCHAR(20),
    id_banco INT(10),
    tipo_CtaBan CHAR(1),
    num_CtaBan NUMERIC(25),
    ingresosM NUMERIC(30),
    gastosM NUMERIC(30),
    patrimonio NUMERIC(30),
    tipoBien VARCHAR(100),
    observaciones VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (cedula),
    CONSTRAINT fkciudades_id_ciudad FOREIGN KEY (id_ciudad)
        REFERENCES ciudades (id_ciudad),
    CONSTRAINT fkbancos_id_banco FOREIGN KEY (id_banco)
        REFERENCES bancos (id_banco),
    UNIQUE KEY cliente_email_unique (email)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contrato (
    p INT NOT NULL,
    g INT NOT NULL,
    o INT NOT NULL,
    cedula VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    contrato INT(50) NOT NULL,
    plazo INT(4) NOT NULL,
    id_monto INT(10) NOT NULL,
    padmin NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,
    pinsc NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,
    pdesg NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,
    padj NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,
    fing DATE NOT NULL,
    fasam DATE,
    tipo_adj CHAR(1),
    estado_p CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    estado_c CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    id_ciudad INT(10) NOT NULL,
    id_asesor INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (p , g , o),
    CONSTRAINT fkcliente_cedula FOREIGN KEY (cedula)
        REFERENCES cliente (cedula),
    CONSTRAINT fkciudades_id_ciudad FOREIGN KEY (id_ciudad)
        REFERENCES ciudades (id_ciudad),
    CONSTRAINT fkasesores_id_asesor FOREIGN KEY (id_asesor)
        REFERENCES asesores (id_asesor),
    CONSTRAINT fkmontos_id_monto FOREIGN KEY (id_monto)
        REFERENCES montos (id_monto)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;
```

Comment: Todo parece correcto. Lo que se me ocurre es que en alguna de las tablas existan ya datos que creen inconsistencia al crear las restricciones.

Answer (score 4):

Los errores que tenias eran:

1. Algunas columnas de la tabla `cliente` les habia faltado agregar el
       `UNSIGNED`
2. En la tabla contrato se cambio el 

       CONSTRAINT
           fkciudades_id_ciudad FOREIGN KEY (id_ciudad) REFERENCES ciudades
           (id_ciudad)

    por 

       CONSTRAINT fkciudades_id_ciudad_contrato FOREIGN KEY
           (id_ciudad) REFERENCES ciudades (id_ciudad)

    ya que se iban a repetir
       las restricciones.

Quedaria asi:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS montos (
    id_monto INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    monto NUMERIC(6 , 2 ) NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_monto)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ciudades (
    id_ciudad INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
    ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    provincia VARCHAR(50),
    agencia CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_ciudad)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bancos (
    id_banco INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
    banco VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    codigo VARCHAR(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_banco)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS asesores (
    id_asesor INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
    nombre VARCHAR(150) COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(150) COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI NOT NULL,
    est_asesor CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    update_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_asesor),
    UNIQUE KEY asesor_email_unique (email)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cliente (
    cedula VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    tipoID CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    nacionalidad VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    est_civil CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    sexo CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    id_ciudad INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    telf_domicilio VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    celular_pers VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    actividad VARCHAR(100),
    profesion VARCHAR(100),
    lugar_trabajo VARCHAR(200),
    cargo VARCHAR(100),
    telefono_t VARCHAR(20),
    celular_t VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_t VARCHAR(255),
    email_t VARCHAR(100),
    ced_conyuge VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_conyuge VARCHAR(255),
    telf_conyuge VARCHAR(20),
    celular_conyuge VARCHAR(20),
    email_conyuge VARCHAR(100),
    nombre_RFamiliar VARCHAR(255),
    telf_RFamiliar VARCHAR(20),
    celular_RF VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_RLaboral VARCHAR(255),
    telf_RLaboral VARCHAR(20),
    celular_RL VARCHAR(20),
    id_banco INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    tipo_CtaBan CHAR(1),
    num_CtaBan NUMERIC(25),
    ingresosM NUMERIC(30),
    gastosM NUMERIC(30),
    patrimonio NUMERIC(30),
    tipoBien VARCHAR(100),
    observaciones VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (cedula),
    CONSTRAINT fkciudades_id_ciudad FOREIGN KEY (id_ciudad)
        REFERENCES ciudades (id_ciudad),
    CONSTRAINT fkbancos_id_banco FOREIGN KEY (id_banco)
        REFERENCES bancos (id_banco),
    UNIQUE KEY cliente_email_unique (email)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contrato (
    p INT NOT NULL,
    g INT NOT NULL,
    o INT NOT NULL,
    cedula VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    contrato INT(50) NOT NULL,
    plazo INT(4) NOT NULL,
    id_monto INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    padmin NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,
    pinsc NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,
    pdesg NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,
    padj NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,
    fing DATE NOT NULL,
    fasam DATE,
    tipo_adj CHAR(1),
    estado_p CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    estado_c CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    id_ciudad INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    id_asesor INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (p,g,o),
   CONSTRAINT fkcliente_cedula FOREIGN KEY (cedula)
        REFERENCES cliente (cedula),
    CONSTRAINT fkciudades_id_ciudad_contrato FOREIGN KEY (id_ciudad)
        REFERENCES ciudades (id_ciudad),
    CONSTRAINT fkasesores_id_asesor_contrato FOREIGN KEY (id_asesor)
        REFERENCES asesores (id_asesor),
    CONSTRAINT fkmontos_id_monto_contrato FOREIGN KEY (id_monto)
        REFERENCES montos (id_monto)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8;
```

Puedes ver aqui [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91938c/1)